# Looking for a way to shard a MongoDB collection from within Python code

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo, sharding

I'm searching for a way to remotely perform sharding on an existing collection, from within a python (2.7) program.
I wasn't able to find an API that performs that (pymongo), or maybe just wasn't looking good enough.

Is such thing possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Follow the instructions for [setting up a sharded cluster](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/), up to the point where you connect the "mongo" shell to the mongos server and say:

```
sh.enableSharding("<database>")
```

Instead, view the code for `enableSharding` by just typing the command without parentheses:

```
sh.enableSharding
```

You can see that it executes `{ enableSharding : dbname }` on the "admin" DB, so do that with [pymongo](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymongo/):

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient()
client.admin.command('enableSharding', 'dbname')
```

Replace 'dbname' with your database name, obviously. Repeat to shard a collection. Get the code from the shell:

```
sh.shardCollection
```

And execute the same command in Python:

```
client.admin.command('shardCollection', 'dbname.collectionname', key={'shardkey': 1})
```

Comment: Thanks.
I'll try it out and see how it goes.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work

`raise OperationFailure`
 `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: no such command: 'enableSharding`